# How do I pass a data source value to a .tfvars file value?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a secret on GCP's Secret Manager.

The secret value is coming from Vault (HCP Cloud).

How can I pass a value of the secret if I'm using a .tfvars file for the values?

Creating the secret without .tfvars works. Other suggestions rather than data source are welcomed as well. I saw that referring locals isn't possible as well inside tfvars.

**vault.tf**:

```
provider "vault" {
  address = "https://testing-vault-public-vault-numbers.numbers.z1.hashicorp.cloud:8200"
  token   = "someToken"
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "secrets" {
  path = "secrets/terraform/cloudcomposer/kafka/"
}
```

**main.tf:**

```
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "connections" {
  provider  = google-beta
  count     = length(var.connections)
  secret_id = "${var.secret_manager_prefix}-${var.connections[count.index].name}"
  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "connections-version" {
  count       = length(var.connections)
  secret      = google_secret_manager_secret.connections[count.index].id
  secret_data = var.connections[count.index].uri
}
```

**dev.tfvars:**

```
image_version                     = "composer-2-airflow-2.1.4"
env_size                          = "LARGE"
env_name                          = "development"
region                            = "us-central1"
network                           = "development-main"
subnetwork                        = "development-subnet1"
secret_manager_prefix = "test"
connections = [
  { name = "postgres", uri = "postgresql://postgres_user:XXXXXXXXXXXX@1.1.1.1:5432/"}, ## This one works
  { name = "kafka", uri = "${data.vault_generic_secret.secrets.data["kafka_dev_password"]}" 
]
```

Getting:

> Error: Invalid expression
> on ./tfvars/dev.tfvars line 39:
> Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Is there an alternative you can think of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values in the tfvars files have to be static, i.e., they cannot use any kind of a dynamic assignment like when using `data` sources. However, in that case, using local variables [1] should be a viable solution:

```
locals {
  connections = [
    {
      name = "kafka",
      uri = data.vault_generic_secret.secrets.data["kafka_dev_password"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, in the resource you need to use it in:

```
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "connections" {
  provider  = google-beta
  count     = length(local.connections)
  secret_id = "${var.secret_manager_prefix}-${local.connections[count.index].name}"
  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "connections-version" {
  count       = length(local.connections)
  secret      = google_secret_manager_secret.connections[count.index].id
  secret_data = local.connections[count.index].uri
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals

Comment: Thanks! I prefer having all values in .tfvars but if it's what I have i'll take the connections out to a locals block.

Comment: This also means I can't deploy secrets per env since today I'm passing env.app.tfvars. Having locals block like this means TF will always deploy all connections every deployment

Comment: You can of course play around, but this is the only way it can work.